# Lower Bound Methods in NonDet Communication Complexity

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, communication-complexity

rank+($M$) is the minimum $r$ such that the following statement holds.

The statement : there exists matrices $U,V$ such that $M = UV$ and $U$ has $r$ columns and $V$ has $r$ rows.

Is rank+($M$) bounded from below by the rectangle covering bound for $M$ ?

Comment: You might wish to provide a bit more background or a pointer to an exposition of the rectangle method, like the Wikipedia article on communication complexity.  Not everyone keeps the basics of communication complexity in cache.

Comment: You seem to be defining just the linear-algebra rank of the matrix M here -- is this your intention or are you trying to define the "positive-rank" which requires U and V to be non-negative?

Comment: Why NonDet appears in the title? As far as I know nondeterministic communication is not lower-bounded by rank or positive-rank (but it is upper-bounded by the positive-rank as showed by Yannakakis). Indeed, if you believe in the log-rank conjecture, then it cannot be lower-bounded by log-rank (because the nondeterministic communication can be exponentially more powerful).

Comment: just to make things clear, when I say positive-rank I mean what @Noam said in his comment, U and V are non-negative. This is just my wording.